# Image isn't at the bottom with gravity(bottom)

Tags: java, android, xml

I am building an app in Android studio and i have a little problem. I have a ImageView in main_activity.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@drawable/login_background"
tools:context="com.example.filip.transport.Activities.MainActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="38dp">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Ime i Prezime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" >
        <Spinner
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Lozinka"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size" />

    <EditText

        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/lozinka"
        android:background="@drawable/border"

        />

    <Button

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Prijava korisnika"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        />


</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/truck_login1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Like u see, i have `gravity="bottom"` and the image is on the bottom of my activity when i test the app on my phone, but when im testing on some other devices(21 api) the image is cca 10 dp above the bottom. Can somebody give me a hint or something? ty

Comment: Can you post the Android Studio preview and the result on the mobile ?

Comment: i think you don't need RelativeLayout in wrap ImageView

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no need of Relative Layout above the ImageView. Also the ImageView has android:layout_centerVertical="true" && android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" , which simply puts the Image at the centre of the screen. Just remove centerVertical property if you want to put the ImageView at the centre Bottom of the screen.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/truck_login1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Comment: Still does'nt work. this is the image on api 21.
http://imgur.com/a/36We6

Answer (score 0):

Either remove RelativeLayout parent for ImageView or add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the RelativeLayout of ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Jatin Jha works. But the image used in the imageView might have some white space around it. Check the image using some image editing software.

Comment: Thanks for the support @Mihir . Even I was puzzled when he said it didn't work.